# ReactJS Wrong Component gets removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have three files: `ShopsContainer.js` `ShopsComponent.js` and `ShopsItemComponent.js`

`ShopsContainer` maintains an array of shop items in local state that gets passed down into `ShopsComponent` as props. `ShopsComponent` then maps through the items array that is being received as props and renders a `ShopsItemComponent` for each item in the array.

Within my `ShopsContainer` file, I have a method that removes a shop item from state using the following code:

```
removeShop = (shopAccount) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    items: prevState.items.filter(shop => {
       return shop.shopAccount !== shopAccount
     })
  }));
}
```

When this happens, the correct item is removed from the items array in state, however, whatever the last `ShopItem` is that is in the DOM at the time of the `removeShop` call will get removed no matter if it is the correct item that should be removed or not. In other words, when `removeShop` gets called and the items array in state gets updated correctly, the wrong `ShopItemComponent` gets removed from the DOM.

What I would like to happen (or what I think should happen) is when `removeShop` gets called, that shop gets removed from the items array in state and `ShopsContainer` re-renders causing `ShopsComponent` to re-render with the updated props being received. And lastly `ShopsComponent` would map through the newly updated items array in props displaying a `ShopItemComponent for the correct items. Perhaps the problem has to do with the props being updated?

My code is as follows:

**ShopsContainer.js**

```
class ShopsContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      items: null
    } 

    this.getAll();
    this.removeShop = this.removeShop.bind(this);
  }

  getAll = () => {
    // API request that fetches items and updates state
  }

  removeShop = (shopAccount) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.filter(shop => {
         return shop.shopAccount !== shopAccount
       })
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items ? <ShopComponent items={this.state.items} removeShop={this.removeShop} /> : <div><h1>Loading...</h1></div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ShopsComponent.js**

```
class ShopsComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
  }

  handleRemove = (shopAccount) => {
    this.props.removeShop(shopAccount);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        {this.props.items.map((shopItem, i) => {
          return (<ShopItemComponent key={i} item={shopItem} removeShop={this.handleRemove} />);
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the `key` should be based on the content, not the position.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `ShopItemComponent` please ? Also you don't need to `bind(this)` in the constructor if you're using arrow functions, they are bound automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working great, but you only has one mistake , your `ShopComponent` is assign index as a `key` for each `ShopItemComponent` and react is tracking those `indexes` to update the correct component, so you need to set key as a unique value between items, then I realize that `shopAccount` should be your `id` for each item.

The solution code is below.

```
class ShopsComponent extends Component {
  handleRemove = (shopAccount) => {
    this.props.removeShop(shopAccount);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        {this.props.items.map((shopItem) => <ShopItemComponent key={shopItem.shopAccount} item={shopItem} removeShop={this.handleRemove} />)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope you can find useful.

> Note, when you are using a arrow function into your class, don't bind that method into the constructor, so remove it, because

```
handleRemove = (shopAccount) => {
  this.props.removeShop(shopAccount);
}
```

is already binded.

Comment: YES! Thanks so much!